# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>'

Tags: c#, generics

I have seen all the solution provided in stackoverflow but did not get solution. Below is my code.

```
private static List<CombinedData> CombineReport(List<TimesheetUserPaycodeReport> timesheetUserPayCodeData, List<TimesheetReportData> reportData)
        {
            List<CombinedData> combinedReportData = new List<CombinedData>();
            return combinedReportData = (from ts in timesheetUserPayCodeData
            join rd in  reportData on new {ts.LoginName,ts.EntryDateString } equals new {rd.LoginName,rd.EntryDateString }
            select new { rd.EmployeeId,rd.LoginName, rd.LastName, rd.FirstName,rd.StartDateString,
                rd.EndDateString,rd.UserId,rd.EntryDateString,rd.ApprovalStatus,ts.PayCodeHours,
                ts.PayCodeCode,rd.ProjectCode,rd.OTRTicket,rd.ActivityCode,rd.ExportOn,rd.ApprovedOnString,rd.SubmittedOnString,rd.TimesheetId}).ToList();
```

I am getting below error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TimeSheetExport.CombinedData>
```

Comment: Error is pretty clear. You're trying to return list of anonymous type from a method which needs to return `List<CombinedData>`

Comment: namespace TimeSheetExport
{
    [DelimitedRecord(",")]
    class CombinedData
    {
        [FieldQuoted]
        public string EmployeeId;
        [FieldQuoted]
        public string LoginName;

Comment: Please don't try to add code in comments - if you want to show more code, please *edit* your question and add it. If you highlight the block of code and hit the `{}` button, we also get nice code formatting as well.

Comment: did you try `.ToList<CombinedData>()`

Comment: Side note: instead of "searched alot" text you should provide links to approaches you've tried along with short description why it did not work in your case.

Answer (score 3):

> You're trying to return list of anonymous type from a method which
>   needs to return List. **new { }** will create
>   **AnonymousType** list, so you need to create your List as
>   return type of your method.

What i guess, your CombinedData class have all field that you are returning, Then just change your query as below:

```
private static List<CombinedData> CombineReport(List<TimesheetUserPaycodeReport> timesheetUserPayCodeData, List<TimesheetReportData> reportData)
        {
            List<CombinedData> combinedReportData = new List<CombinedData>();
            return combinedReportData = (from ts in timesheetUserPayCodeData
            join rd in  reportData on new {ts.LoginName,ts.EntryDateString } equals new {rd.LoginName,rd.EntryDateString }
            select new CombinedData   /// Create CombinedData object here, not anonymous type
            {  
              EmployeeId = rd.EmployeeId,
              LoginName = rd.LoginName, 
              LastName = rd.LastName, 
             ------ so on for remaining fields
             }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You trying create list of anonimus type instead List.
Try

```
... select new CombinedData(rd.EmployeeId,rd.LoginName, rd.LastName, rd.FirstName,rd.StartDateString,
            rd.EndDateString,rd.UserId,rd.EntryDateString,rd.ApprovalStatus,ts.PayCodeHours,
            ts.PayCodeCode,rd.ProjectCode,rd.OTRTicket,rd.ActivityCode,rd.ExportOn,rd.ApprovedOnString,rd.SubmittedOnString,rd.TimesheetId);
```